# TDD inject Mocked Repository(UnitOfWork) into internal constructor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, tdd, repository

I am looking into TDD and I have come across a scenario that I could use some help with.

My project uses MVC3 and is structured to have a BAL and a DAL layer.  Each layer is in its own project.  The BAL accesses the database through the Repository Pattern.  Since I am using the EntityFramework, I also implemented the UnitOfWork pattern.  Here is what a service class in the BAL looks like:

```
public class ExampleService
{
    private UnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    private bool isProcessing = false;

    internal ExampleService(UnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
    public void ExposedMethod()
    {
        //do stuff with the unitOfWork
    }
}
```

Question: I would like to create a unit test for this (obviously I should have written the test before the code).  If I run the code as is, however, the test will be an integration test as it will use the UnitOfWork and connect to my database.  I could mock up a new UnitOfWork that accesses dummy data in memory, but I don't understand how to inject it as the constructor is internal.  I would rather not write unit tests that reside inside each project.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could decorate the assembly containing this class with the [`[InternalsVisibleTo]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute in order to make all internal members visible the unit test project.

Another possibility is to make this constructor public as this would make the class more reusable. Normally the DI wireup should be done in the outermost layer of the architecture (GUI) and for this constructors of the different dependencies need to be public. This allows for this DAL layer to be reused in other projects.

Comment: [InternalsVisibleTo] will solve my question as is. I may still be missing something with DI, but the example class I showed is in the BAL, the UnitOfWork is in the DAL.  I have the constructor marked internal because I have another class that controls access to the example class.  I will have to consider this a bit more.  Thanks!